# How to properly handle exceptions raised in the __aiter__ method of an asynchronous iterator in FastAPI?

Tags: python, error-handling, stream, fastapi, openai-api

I'm working on a project using FastAPI and OpenAI's GPT-3 API, where I'm implementing an asynchronous iterator (**aiter**) to stream responses from the GPT-3 API to the frontend. However, I'm facing difficulties in handling exceptions raised within the **aiter** method and propagating them to the frontend.
this is my code looks like

```
# StreamGenerator class implementing __aiter__ method

class StreamGenerator:
    async def __aiter__(self):
        try:
            # Code block with potential exceptions
            # ...
        except Exception as e:
            raise StreamGeneratorError("An error occurred while processing the request.") from e

# FastAPI route using the StreamGenerator

@router.post("/v1/chat-with-ai")
async def chat_gpt_api_view(body: UserPrompt) -> StreamingResponse:
    try:
        stream_gen_instance = StreamGenerator()
        response = StreamingResponse(stream_gen_instance, media_type='text/event-stream')
        return response
    except StreamGeneratorError as e:
        # Handle StreamGeneratorError and return appropriate response
        # ...
```

The problem I'm facing is that when an exception is raised within the **aiter** method, it doesn't seem to propagate to the FastAPI route handler, and the response code remains 200 OK instead of returning an error response.

I've tried raising a custom exception (StreamGeneratorError) within the **aiter** method and handling it in the FastAPI route, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to properly handle exceptions raised in the **aiter** method of an asynchronous iterator in FastAPI and propagate them to the frontend?